# Do I always need to implement fields and properties in a constructor?

Tags: c#, properties, constructor, field

Something got me thinking today.

I am a beginning programmer and I am wondering if it is necessary to implement fields and properties in a constructor.

Could someone give me an example of:

1. when to do this and why do I want to do this

&

2. when not to do this and why I don't want to do this

Thanks in advance

Comment: No.  And trying it would have told you immediately.  Before you ask another question, go snag CLR Via C#, skip the first two chapters, and read.

Comment: I don't really have an example. I am not 100% sure when I have fields en properties to put them in a constructor yes or now. Is this only necessary when you want to use those values for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a constructor as it's name implies is to "construct" *properly* an object. The word *properly* depends solely on our perspective. For instance, let that we want to declare a class that will represent a `Customer` in a system.

This can be done with many ways:

**First way**

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Second way**

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    public Customer(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

and many other ways...

Let's take the first way. In this case you could create a customer object using the default parameterless constructor.

```
var customer = new Customer();
```

Apparently, in this case the `FirtsName` and `LastName` would be null. You have to set these values later, if it is needed.

On the other hand, using the second way, you can only create a customer object providing values both for the firstName and the lastName.

Both approaches are correct as also the rest approaches are correct, provided that they meet your requirements.

```
var customer = new Customer("firstname","lastname");
```